# Should I accept technically correct answer or the answer which is the solution for me?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

I asked the following question.

[How to close a website for a few months without affecting SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107036/how-to-close-a-website-for-a-few-months-without-affecting-seo)

It got two answers.

Answer 01 :[How to close a website for a few months without affecting SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107036/how-to-close-a-website-for-a-few-months-without-affecting-seo/107038#107038)

Answer 02 :[How to close a website for a few months without affecting SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107036/how-to-close-a-website-for-a-few-months-without-affecting-seo/107037#107037)

Answer 02 is the technical answer and it is correct for my question.

Answer 01 is not a technical answer and he suggest a alternative way to solve my problem. But that is the **most practical** answer for **me** (Again I repeat it is **for me**). So accepted it. But I feel like it is unfair because Answer 01 is technically correct answer. Should I accept answer 01 or 02?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have the choice, for yourself.**

As the tooltip says

> Click to accept this answer because it solved **your** problem or was the most helpful in finding **your** solution

So from your perspective, you only need to accept the answer that's right **for you**. If other people think another one is better, they will vote it up. In this case latecomers will see an accepted answer with lower score than another. Again, their situation may be different from yours, and which answer they choose is completely **their own concerns**. There's no need for you to care about latecomers. **The right one *for you* is right.**

This is exactly how the whole Stack Exchange network works. People ask questions and accept answers. Latecomers see possible solutions and the one the OP has accepted, and they work out the ones for their own questions. Your acceptance is only your concern, and it's no more than essentially a reference for others, although it's a little different from others.

Answer (score 2):

#### It is up to you.

The accept pipe is essentially a special vote (and so is it registered also in the db). It says, "next to the 5 people thinking A's answer is useful and to the 8 thinking B's answer, the OP says A is the good solution".

In your case I had chosen the other one, thinking to the googlers of the future. Despite that not this had I followed. It had been another important reason, that I don't want to see years later in the comments that *"this should be the accepted answer"* and similar critics.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, the merits of an answer will be proven through the voting of the general community. However, in terms of choosing which answer to *accept*, I feel it is important taking note of the actual roll-over description for accepting an answer.

> Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem *or was the most helpful in finding **your** solution*

As far as I am concerned, you should always accept the answer that was most helpful for *you* to find a solution. In fact, I have previously requested users accept alternate answers after accepting my own, on the basis that they had left comments on the alternate answers explaining that they *were* the most helpful, in the askers case.

In this case, it *sounds* like your saying answer one is most practical, and thus more helpful to your specific case. It may not be the best *overall* answer, but again, that is what votes are for. If you think the other answer still has *practical merit*, you can upvote it.